# Loading mixed .NET reference assemblies throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to load a. NET 6 assembly and its reference assemblies into a custom assembly load context, but my code kept throwing exceptions about loading mixed assemblies into collectible assembly load contexts.

I temporarily changed my load context to be non collectible but now it's throwing a BadImageFormatException for certain reference assemblies. I don't know much about mixed assemblies other than that they can contain both managed and unmanaged code, and there seems to be conflicting information regarding how much support there is for them in .NET.

It didn't seem to be an issue in. NET Framework but this assembly is from a project that was upgraded to. NET, so I'm wondering is what I'm trying to do when possible now in the latter.

Any advice appreciated, cheers